# RestKit: Handling unexpected objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, restkit

I have a mapping which expects an `NSDictionary` for a certain path, but there's a bug in the API I'm using right now so it returns an `NSArray` instead of an `NSDictionary` when the object is empty. How would I gracefully handle bugs like this?

Right now, RestKit takes the empty `NSArray` and creates an `NSDictionary` object on the mapped class object, and this `NSDictionary` has a single key which is an empty array, i.e. printing `dictionary.allKeys` gives:

```
<__NSArrayI 0xc953940>(
    <__NSArrayI 0xc94f610>(

    )
)
```

Where it would normally look like:

```
<__NSArrayI 0xc953940>(
    stringKey1,
    stringKey2
)
```

What happens then is that AFNetworking crashes as it tries to send `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` to what it expects is an array of strings but is actually an array with an empty array.

Why does this happen and how do I handle it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Really need to see an exception message and stack trace, but, 2 potential solutions:

1. Use an `RKDynamicMapping` to analyse the incoming object and decide if mapping should continue or be aborted
2. Use KVC validation on the destination object to verify the mapped content and reject if invalid

They're probably about the same amount of code in each case, but the code is in different places. Option 2 may be after your exception so I'd look to option 1 initially.

Comment: I find it odd that I would have to use a `RKDynamicMapping` to analyse the incoming object, because I would have to do that to every single incoming object then. I would expect RestKit to react in some way to objects it knows are not what it is expecting.

Comment: Generally, how could it? The server should really return a response code indicating an error and the same type of data for each request to a set path.